# Newline to txt file python

Tags: python, text-files

I am trying to create a simple program which asks users for input then puts it into  a txt file but my problem is that it's not going into a new row.

```
user1=input(ex.Day1)
user2=input(ex.Day2)
```

The result in my txt file now is

```
Day1Day2
```

I want to achieve

```
Day1
Day2
```

in my txt file.
This is the code that I used.

```
fout = open("savedplans.txt", "w")
    fout.writelines(plan_list )
    fout.close()
```

Please help me and thanks!

Comment: This is not the whole code. What is in `plan_list` exactly? You can try `fout.writelines('\n'.join(plan_list))`

Comment: Where is `plan_list` defined?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following:

```
fout.write("\n".join(plan_list))
```

or

```
fout.writelines("%s\n" % l for l in plan_list)
```

You can also use `with` for file operation:

```
with open("savedplans.txt", "w") as fout:
    fout.write("\n".join(plan_list))
    # fout.writelines("%s\n" % l for l in plan_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

If `plan_list` contains the lines to be written, then use this code.

```
fi = open("hello.txt","w")
for item in ["Hello","World"]:
    fi.write(item+"\n")
```